derivative of the inverse transpos of a second order tensor with itself
consider $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a second order tensor, and $\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}$ the invers traspos of the same tensor. Is it correct to take the derivative of the $\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}$ with respect to itself in the following indesies?
$$
\mathcal{H}_{iIjJ} = \frac{\partial\boldsymbol{F}^{-T}}{\partial\boldsymbol{F}} = -F_{iJ}^{-T}F_{jI}^{-T}
$$
